# Swift ios cant get animation to be infinite

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a animation that I want to be infinite

```
var rotateRock: Bool = true
    func rotateRock() {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.7, delay: 2.7, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.curveLinear], animations:
                {
                    self.rockImg.transform.ty += 155
                    if self.rotateRock {
                    self.rotateRock = false
                    self.rockImg.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)
                } else {
                    self.rotateRock = true
                    self.rockImg.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
                }

            },completion: nil)
        }
```

Then I call `rotateRock()` inside `viewDidLoad()` this works, the animation never stops which is what I want.

If I now enter another VC that is presented modally then exit it so I end up in my first VC the animation is still running which I want.

But if I change VC by clicking on another tab in my tab bar and then go back the animation has stopped. Is there any way to check if the animation has stopped so that I can restart it?

Comment: Do it in `viewDidAppear()`?

Comment: What about calling it in `viewWillAppear` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override viewDidAppear() and call rotateRock there. That should work.

Edit:
What Matt says below is true, viewDidAppear would work but maybe it would be better viewWillAppear to make sure you don't see it before starting.

Comment: Actually `viewWillAppear` might be better. If we wait until `viewDidAppear`, the user will see the "stopped" animation briefly before it starts.

Comment: I tried to use both ``viewDidAppear()`` and ``viewWillAppear`` the first time I load the app it works fine. But when I switch VC and go back again to reset the animation it only half of the animation works. It moves the image view upwards but this time it does not rotate the image if you look at my code this part does not work when running the animation again: ``self.rockImg.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI/2))``

Comment: I solved the rotate problem, problem was when the animation runs for the second time it will try to rotate the image form where it stoped, which means it does not have to rotate more. I updated my qustion with the working code